# Getting undefined method `each' for "":String in Rails after submitted

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nomethoderror

Getting this error after submitting a form:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Xk0.png]

```
 def create
   @user = User.new(user_params)
   if @user.save
     log_in @user
     redirect_to @user
   else
     render 'new'

   end
 end
```

Comment: could you please give more info on the error, such as the error trace itself, and the file from which the error occurred specifically.

Comment: I would guess that `user_params` is a string, but Rails expects it to be a hash-like structure.

Comment: If I remove the user_params, then it works fine. But that's not what I want.

Comment: could you provide `user_params` method